# Acrobat Javascript in Chrome: how to trigger a HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, acrobat

I'm working on an intelligent PDF file. It's supposed to send some simple data to a certain URL:

```
this.getURL('https://something.com/data1/data2/data3');
```

However this doesn't work if the PDF was opened in a browser, only in Acrobat Reader. Apparently browsers only support a very limited subset of JavaScript within the already very limited Acrobat JavaScript.

Is there a way to get around this?

I can add a button to the form and ask the user to click it. It's lame, but better than nothing. But then I can only open a hardcoded URL and can't send any dynamic data with it.

I wonder if it's possible to programmatically trigger a button?

If neither works, is it possible to try to "talk" to Chrome from inside the PDF reader?

(Bonus question to whoever flagged this question: what part isn't clear for you?)

Comment: I am not aware of any web browser supporting any Acrobat JavaScript. You might try a Link (but without JavaScript)

Comment: Chrome and Edge both support PDF-embedded JavaScript, but both are very limited. Firefox doesn't support any advanced PDF features at all.

Comment: What are you using to create the PDF?

Comment: OpenOffice and PDFill.

Comment: Is there a problem with using a pdf form [created with latex](https://martin-thoma.com/creating-pdf-forms-with-latex/) instead with bare urls?

Comment: I'm not a big expert on PDF magic, but does it matter what is used to produce it? Browsers still block most of embedded JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here are the answers.

You can't trigger a HTTP request from Javascript unless the PDF is opened in Adobe Acrobat Reader, and period.

It is possible to add a PDF form with a Submit button to the document with a HTTP POST request as action, but that will also only work in Acrobat Reader. Chrome and Edge will send the POST, but with an empty request body, and Firefox won't do anything.

No, it's not possible to programmatically click a button.

No, it's not possible to call a JavaScript function on the browser from the PDF document.

All in all, just forget using Acrobat Javascript for anything, as it will never be even remotely reliable.

Comment: Please do not teach new users that asking several questions and expecting post with answers to all of them is the right way of using the community.

Comment: @Yunnosch It's self-answered.. and the account is not new :)

Comment: @Scratte It still serves as the wrong precedence of asking multiples-questions and having an answer.